# List inline policies attached to a role using boto3

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto3, amazon-iam

I want to list all the inline policies attached to a role.
I tried using **role_list=client.list_attached_role_policies(RoleName=role_name)**, but it returns list of managed policies only and not the inline policies.
How can I get list of inline polices attached to a role using boto3.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use [list_role_policies](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/iam.html#IAM.Client.list_role_policies):

> Lists the names of the **inline policies** that are embedded in the specified IAM role.

Comment: Quick note: your workload needs to have the following permission: [iam:ListRolePolicies](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/APIReference/API_ListRolePolicies.html)